# search and replace in fasta sequence

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

i am looking for some one liner solution to search and replace using wild character..

Input:

```
>sequence1
ATGCCAAACTGGAACT[A/T]ATTCAATGGCATGGACATAAATTC[A/C]ATACAATTACAAA
>sequnce2
ATCAAACCGGTATGTACATT[A,T/G]ATTCATTACTA
```

output:

```
>sequence1
ATGCCAAACTGGAACTNATTCAATGGCATGGACATAAATTCNATACAATTACAAA
>sequnce2
ATCAAACCGGTATGTACATTNATTCATTACTA
```

i need to replace everything in betwee "[" and "]" with "N" . the data length might vary. 
i was able to find the pattern using the awk script but dont know how to replace it. help please..

```
awk -F'[][]' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i=i+2) print $i}' 1.fasta
```

another thing i tried is vi editor

```
:%s/[.*\]/N/g
```

using above one, its replacing everything "[A/T]ATTCAATGGCATGGACATAAATTC[A/C]" to N

Comment: [.*] matches everything (.*) from the first [ in the line to the LAST ] in the line. You need [[^]*] instead to match everything from the first [ to the FIRST ] after it.

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this :

```
perl -pe 's/\[.*?\]/N/g' file.txt
```

**EXPLANATIONS** (about [regex)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex)

- `s///` is the basic substitution *skeleton* (for `perl` or `sed`) : `s/before/after/`
- `s///g` : the `g` modifier at the end, means *all occurences*
- `\[` : means : a literal `[` (or anything else *backslashed* instead)
- `.` : means : *any character*
- `*` means : *0 or N character(s)*
- `?` tell last regex to be in *not greedy* mode

That said, I have another *funny* solution :

```
perl -ne 'print join "N", split /\[.*?\]/;' file.txt
```

Maybe more clear like this ?! (but still the same)

```
perl -ne '
    print join(
        "N",
        split(/\[.*?\]/)
    );
' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\[[^]]*\]/N/g' file
```

EDIT: explantion as requested:

Look for a literal "[" ([) then any sequence of zero or more non-"]" characters ([^]]*) followed by a literal "]" (]) and replace that whole string with the letter N. Do it "g"lobally across each line.

Answer (score 0):

just add another awk one-liner.
your goal is substitution, no need to play with $x

```
awk '{gsub(/\[[^\]]*\]/,"N")}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in vi editor:

```
%s/\[[^\]]*\]/N/g
```